# Why changes in my.ini file doesn't affect?

Tags: mysql, database, configuration

I have added few properties in my.ini file and restarted the server but unfortunately, it doesn't gets affected when I run a command `show variables;`

Few properties I have added to my.ini file are

```
# created and no character set is defined
    character-set-server=utf8
    collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci



 [mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking=
# enable-named-pipe=
# shared-memory=

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

# Path to the installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
# basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/"

# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data
```

but it still shows different values
[image]

Please help me, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: My my.ini file is located at C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag since this is for MySQL.  They are not the same.

Comment: *it still shows different values* WHAT values are different? be more precise.

Comment: And show `show variables like '%coll%';` output in textual form, not all variables as a picture.

Comment: @Akina I have attached the image for the show variables results.

Comment: @Akina I am setting below values in 
# master my.ini
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci

But those are not getting reflected

Comment: Execute `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` - does `utf8_unicode_ci` is listed in output?

Comment: @Akina
No it is not listed, only below one listed for utf8

| utf8     | UTF-8 Unicode                   | utf8_general_ci     |      3 |

Comment: I hope you understand that the attempt to use charset and/or collation unknown to server cannot be successful?

Comment: Okay, but datadir value is also different from the my.ini file when I execute show variables command
datadir value in my.ini file 
# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data

datadir value when I do show variables;
| datadir   | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\         |

sorry for the formatting issues.

Comment: @Akina
I have a few more properties from my .ini file to the question

Comment: This makes to think that some different .INI file is specified in the service execution line. Check. If not specified at all - specify explicitly.